# How to use models from different domain in frontend's site controller?

Tags: yii2

How to use models from different domain in frontend's site controller. Actually we are currently useing Yii2 Advanced framework, where we want to keep our backend at different domain & frontend at different domain so we require some backend models in frontend, then how can I give the path of backend's controller in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

simply adding the related use of namespace involved inside your controller

If your models are in common

```
use common\models\YuorModel;
```

or if they are in backend

```
use backend\models\YuorModel;
```

or frontend

```
    use frontend\models\YuorModel;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I think you didn't get my question actually I want to deploy frontend at different domain & backend at different domain just like xyz.com/frontend & admin.xyz/backend my domains are different, that time how to use backend's controller in frontend?

Comment: You should redefine the namespace for the frontend and the backend files involeved and redifine the related  use.   yourdomani\models\...etc

Comment: I have added namespace like <?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
namespace http://admin.xyz.com/backend/models; then I got error 
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) or ';' or '{

Comment: Please show a sample of your actual code and a few reference of the domain/project .. controller structure you desire..

Comment: I'm using /backend/models/someModel in my frontend's SiteController as - 'use backend\models\someModel;' because my backend is in same project(domain). but now I've to use backend from a different domain. Therefore I was trying to use it as - 'www.domain.com\backend\models\someModel', but it's not worked. So, help me if you got it correctly.

Comment: if you change ony the project name alias what you call "domain" you don't need to do nothings.  (it seems that you want to copy the contents of a project in a new directory .. if it is so you do not have to do anything except check in config / main.php if cis ono any absolute paths ..)

Comment: Anyway use question update for new code information.. is more readible than comment..

Answer (score 0):

If both domain names are pointing to the same server, then this is possible.
So if you are using the advanced template as the basis of your project but `backend` folder is at a different folder from the `frontend` folder, you have to change the alias path in `common`->`boostrap` file.

For example, this might be the folder structure in your server where the common folder is outside of both domains folder.

```
- public_html
----- xyz.com
--------- frontend
----- common
--------- config
------------- bootstrap.php
----- admin.xyz
--------- backend
```

Your bootstrap.php contents should be like this.

```
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/xyz.com/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/admin.xyz/backend');
```

Then in your frontend controller the first few lines should be like this.

```
namespace frontend\controllers;
use backend\models\TheModelToUse;
```

If you want to use more than one models from `backend` app, you have to add each of them accordingly.